# How to calculate a day difference like a SQL Windows function in R

Tags: r, date-difference

**Input:**

[image]

**Aim:**

Create a new column named 'dayDifference' with the following rule: for each pair 'item-city' pair calculate the day difference of the related pair.

**Desired output:**

[image]

- Row 1 and 2 [Pair Piza-Berlin] correspond to 3 because there is 3 days between 2 Feb and 4 Feb
- Row 3 [Pair Pizza-Hambourg] correspond to 0 because there is no day difference
- Row 4 and 5 [Pair Pasta-Hambourg] correspond to 21 because there is 21 days from 10 to 20
- Row 6 [Pair Pasta-Berlin] correspond to 0 because there is no day difference

Info: Of course there can be more than 2 rows of pair [for instance I can have the pair 'pizza-berlin' 100 rows : if so always take the max(date) and substract to the min(date) pizza-berlin pair.

**Constraint:**

Need to be done in R [e.g. no outside connection with a database]

**Source code:**

```
df <- structure(list(id = c(4848L, 4887L, 4899L, 4811L, 4834L, 4892L
), item = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Pasta", 
"Pizza"), class = "factor"), city = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L), .Label = c("Berlin", "Hamburg"), class = "factor"), 
    date = structure(c(17199, 17201, -643892, 17449, 17459, 17515
    ), class = "Date")), .Names = c("id", "item", "city", "date"
), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Row 1 and 2 [Pair Piza-Berlin] wouln't correspond to 2 because there is a difference of 2 days between 2nd Feb and 4th Feb?

Comment: And for [Pair Pasta-Hambourg] difference should be 10?

Comment: @suchait I appologies, you are perfectely right. It's updated .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Reduce` is an awesome function

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(item, city) %>% 
  mutate(dayDifference=abs(Reduce(`-`, as.numeric(range(date)))))

# A tibble: 6 x 5
# Groups:   item, city [4]
     id   item    city       date dayDifference
  <int> <fctr>  <fctr>     <date>         <dbl>
1  4848  Pizza  Berlin 2017-02-02             2
2  4887  Pizza  Berlin 2017-02-04             2
3  4899  Pizza Hamburg 0207-02-01             0
4  4811  Pasta Hamburg 2017-10-10            10
5  4834  Pasta Hamburg 2017-10-20            10
6  4892  Pasta  Berlin 2017-12-15             0
```

Comment: Hello thanks, this is a nice solution I think. I find the functional approach to reduce interesting. Neverthless, I am quite surprised that we need to use the group-by. Usually in SQL the group by will create an agregation. Neverthless if I run only until group-by the code you gave, I get the same number of observation as the table df... This makes me a bit confused. Is the group_by function in dplyr a bit different of SQL?

Comment: Group_by does not aggregate, it merely sets the scope for the follow on function

Comment: Ad I think I found a nice tutorial : file:///C:/Users/i342097/Downloads/data-transformation.pdf. @dmi3kno many thanks for the infos that helps. It's indeed a bit confusing name for SQL users :) but now I got it

Answer (score 2):

I would do it using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[, min_date := min(date), by = c("item", "city")]
df[, max_date := max(date), by = c("item", "city")]
df[, dayDifference := difftime(max_date, min_date, units = "days")]
df[, c("min_date", "max_date") := NULL]
```

It'll give you desired output:

```
id  item    city       date             dayDifference
1: 4848 Pizza  Berlin 2017-02-02        2 days
2: 4887 Pizza  Berlin 2017-02-04        2 days
3: 4899 Pizza Hamburg 0207-02-01        0 days
4: 4811 Pasta Hamburg 2017-10-10       10 days
5: 4834 Pasta Hamburg 2017-10-20       10 days
6: 4892 Pasta  Berlin 2017-12-15        0 days
```

You can also use `df[, dayDifference := max_date - min_date]` instead of `df[, dayDifference := difftime(max_date, min_date, units = "days")]`.

Answer (score 0):

Not pretty, but...

```
i<-unique(lapply(1:nrow(df),function(x) which(paste(df[,2],df[,3]) %in% paste(df[x,2],df[x,3]))))
for(j in 1:length(i)) df[i[[j]],"days"]<-abs(difftime(df[i[[j]],][1,"date"],df[i[[j]],][2,"date"]))

> df
    id  item    city       date days
1 4848 Pizza  Berlin 2017-02-02    2
2 4887 Pizza  Berlin 2017-02-04    2
3 4899 Pizza Hamburg 0207-02-01   NA
4 4811 Pasta Hamburg 2017-10-10   10
5 4834 Pasta Hamburg 2017-10-20   10
6 4892 Pasta  Berlin 2017-12-15   NA
```